# I am learning socket but my code but i am not being able to connect to a port

Tags: python, sockets, port

```
#server
import socket
s = socket.socket()
print("Socket connected")
s.bind((socket.gethostname(),9999))
s.listen(3)
print("waiting for connection")
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print("connected with",addr)
    c.send(bytes("Welcome!","utf-8"))
    c.close()

#client
import socket
c = socket.socket()
c.connect((socket.gethostname(),9999))
msg = c.recv(1024)
print(msg.decode("utf-8"))
```

i am getting error after running client saying : OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is stating that the port you are trying to bind to is currently in use.
Even if you stop the program, after binding the port remains occupied for a time duration of few minutes.

You need to enable the `reuse address` option before binding to ports in your code.

Here is how you can do that:

```
s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

You can get details in below link :

http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/addrinuse.html